# putenv has been disabled for security reasons when executing composer commands

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, composer-php

I am studying Laravel. I installed php 7, mysql and nginx using WinNMP. I installed composer and , throught it, I installed laravel cli (Laravel\Installer). I am getting "putenv has been disabled for security reasons" all the time since I created the Laravel skeleton application. I got this message when accessing my Laravel application on the browser at the first launch, I got rid of this error by deleting this function wherever it appeared in \vendor\symfony\console\application.php. I know that it is a silly solution but I am just studying. But now I am learning Migration and I need to execute some commands I am getting this error again. The command in question is "composer dump-autoload", I got this message on the console:

```
  Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer on line 52


 [ErrorException]
  putenv() has been disabled for security reasons
```

Obs. I've already deleted this function from disable_function on php.ini file

Comment: I uninstalled composer and now the dump-autoload command is working.

Answer (score 11):

In the php.ini file, search and remove `putenv` if you found in inside the "**disable_functions=**" .

Comment: did you restart your server?

Answer (score 3):

All what you need to do is disable `putenv` inside `php.ini` file under `disable_functions`

If you don't know how to find `php.ini` do the following steps:

First, check your php version by typing in your terminal:

```sh
php -v
```

next search for `php.ini` file by typing:

```sh
find / -name php.ini
```

After finding the correct `php.ini` edit it with your preferred code editor.

Let's use `nano`

```sh
nano /path/to/php.ini
```

Look at **disable_functions** section or searching for `putenv` by hitting `Ctrl + ^` and type **putenv** and Enter.

Remove `putenv` and hit `Ctrl + x` and save the file.

That's all! You are good to go and do your stuff.